# Get password for Signed apk

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my app in play Store Before some times.

Now I want to upgrade my app with new version. So I generate a signed apk for new version.

When I Upload my apk file, Play store gives me error that Your apk signed with different key.

I forget my old passord in previous version signed apk.

So Now My Question is how i can get my Old passord. Or any other option to put app in play Store again.

Please help me i am Confuse. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can't.  Remember your old password or release a new app.  There are no alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way around that. You must sign all updates with the same exact key. If you no longer have access to that key, you can't update the app. Instead you'll have to unpublished your existing app, change the package name on your update and setup a new listing for a new app under the new package name. Don't lose the key again. Your existing users may not realise you've done all of this so it's bad that you have to release again.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible.

You have to use the same private key to sign your new apk.

If you really forgot the pwd of your key or your have lost your key, we have to say sorry.